# Не могу загрузить windows с загрузочной флешки

Tags: windows, bios, пк

После выбора загрузочного диска появляется ето[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мигает в поле DDR2 at Bank(s). Клавиатура не работает. В чем проблема ?

Comment: Откуда качал винду? Какую винду? Чем записывал?

Comment: Пробовал разные варианты windows 7/10 , linux ubuntu/mint . При всех вариантах появляется ето окно.Записывал винду через Ultra ISO. Вот одна ссылка  https://rutracker.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5839356

Comment: На ноутбуке открывал загрузочную флешку, все работает.

Comment: 1. Почему ты качаешь какую-то порносборку очередного Васяна, а не используешь ванильный iso? 2. Почему качнув на рутрекере порносборку ты идёшь за помощью сюда, а не в тему раздачи? 3. Если я правильно нагуглил cpu id `0f49` - зачем ты пытаешься поставить 64-х битную ОСь на 32-х битный проц?

Comment: Потому что я думаю проблема не в сборке. Я пробовал открывать ее на ноутбуке и там открывается нормально. А на моем ПК до самой загрузки даже не доходит. Даже не открывает флешку.

Comment: `Потому что я думаю проблема не в сборке`. `интегрированы драйверы Intel USB 3.0`. Конкретно к твоей проблеме это не относится, но могу показать примерно пару десятков случаев, когда дрова от Интел на усб воткнутые на контроллер от Асмедиа или на тот же Интел, но немного другой версии - ушатывали комп в вечную синьку. Причём не помогал даже безопасный режим (я про win7, если что). Так что у меня очень большие вопросы к конкретному маминому порносборщику. `Выключена дефрагментация , файл подкачки и гибернация.`. Дефрагментация НЕ нужна на новых ссд со встроенным в контроллер TRIM.

Comment: Во всех остальных случаях - она точно не мешает. А когда у тебя выключеная подкачка и какая-нить прога съедает всю оперативу - становится очень весело работать. `Твики` КАКИЕ? `Отключён автозапуск и недавние документы` по первому - ок, вторым люди активно пользуются. И это только беглый взгляд на описание.

Comment: По пунктам `2` и `3` есть комментарии?

Comment: И у меня не ссд. А старый виндовс не работает. Можно ли отключить дефрагментацию в биосе ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103708/discussion-between-don-rumata-and-fedia-cholak).

Comment: Спасибо, жду вас в чате